# How to perform focused scan of public IP using nmap?

Tags: ip, nmap, router, ports, network-scanners

Scanning my router using the private IP address using nmap reveals the open ports:

[image]

Obtaining the public IP address of the router can be achieved by executing the command:

```
nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com
```

If I scan my router using the public IP address, I get a whole more open ports than those revealed in the scan using the private IP address:

[image]

Am not sure why is that; If I scan the public IP for the ports found in the private IP scan, I get the same result of the private IP scan as expected:

```
nmap -p 21,22,23,80,139,445,5431 <Public_IP>
```

How can I perform accurate scan of a public IP address to reveal the actually open ports of the corresponding device?

Comment: If you want to know what services are provided to the internet on the public IP address, then you need to scan it from outside, not from behind the router which has this public IP. Accessing the public IP from inside might give different results from accessing it from outside.

Comment: We have had many questions like this, let me find a duplicate. In short, you aren't scanning your router. You're scanning the ISP infrastructure in front of your router.

Comment: If you want to scan the router without the infrastructure, then you need to find a way to get inbetween your ISP and your router (usually by putting another router in front) and scanning the private IP that would normally be facing the Internet).

Comment: @schroeder Am not interested in my router, but from what I understand devices on LAN have private IP addresses and share the router's public IP address when connected to the Internet. Scanning arbitrary public addresses reveal the same result of the above scan on my router's public IP. So am not sure how nmap is useful for scanning public IPs.

Comment: So, it looks like you need to understand how routers work first (look up NAT and port forwarding) before you reach for a nmap scan. And, as I said, you are scanning the ISP infrastructure. Networks are very, very complex beasts. You can't aim a random tool at an IP and get perfect, easy-to-understand, data. nmap is very useful, for those who understand networking.

Comment: @schroeder That's what am trying to learn and the purpose of my question. Am not saying nmap is not useful, am trying to learn how to use it on public IPs and get correct/accurate result.

Comment: Then this isn't a security question but a networking question, and you need to start there. Scanning a residential IP from another residential IP has a ton of ISP infrastructure in the way. You won't get great results.